# Perform the integral $ \frac{1}{\pi a_0^{3}} \int \frac{e^{\frac{-2r}{a_0}}}{|r-R|} d^3r $

Tags: integration, exponential-function

For a problem in quantum mechanics, I need to perform this integral:
$$\int \frac{\psi(r)^2}{|r-R|} d^3r $$ where $\psi(r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}a_0^{\frac{3}{2}}}e^{\frac{-r}{a_0}} $. So eventually it comes down to solve:
$$ \frac{1}{\pi a_0^{3}} \int \frac{e^{\frac{-2r}{a_0}}}{|r-R|} d^3r $$

I tried the substitution with t = r-R, so I got:
$$ \frac{1}{\pi a_0^{3}}e^{\frac{-2R}{a_0}} \int \frac{e^{\frac{-2t}{a_0}}}{|t|} d^3t $$

but I didn't know how to go further with it.
The solution must be:
$$\frac{1}{R}\left[1 - (1+\frac{R}{a_0})e^{\frac{-2R}{a_0}}\right]$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are $r$ and $R$ vectors? (i.e. $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{R}$) By $e^{\mathbf{r}}$ do you mean $\mathbf{1} - \mathbf{r} + \frac{\mathbf{r}\cdots \mathbf{r}}{2!} - \cdots$ or do you mean something like $\mathbf{u}=(e^{r_x},e^{r_y},e^{r_z})$? Are the limits $\pm \infty$? I'm assuming there are limits because your solution doesn't seem to depend on $\mathbf{r}$

Comment: $r$ is a vector and $R$ is a constant. By $e^r$  I mean $1-r+..$. The limits of the integration are from $0$ to infinity. And the element $d^3r$ can be seen as a volume element so $r^2 dr sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta$. Hope this clears thing up.